# Getting an SCNPhysicsVehicle's Position

Tags: scenekit

I am working on a basic racing game using Apple's [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework/index.html) and am running into issues simulating a car. Using the [SCNPhysicsVehicle](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsVehicle_Class/) behavior, I am able to properly set up the car and drive it using the documented methods.

However, I am unable to get the car's position. It seems logical that the SCNPhysicsVehicle would move the SCNNodes that contain the chassis and the wheels as the car moves but the SCNNodes remain at their original position and orientation. Strangely enough, the chassis' SCNPhysicsBody's velocity remains accurate throughout the simulation so I can assume that the car's position is based off of the SCNPhysicsBody and not the SCNNode. Unfortunately, there is no documented method that I have found to get an SCNPhysicsBody's position.

Getting a car's position should be trivial and is essential to create a racing game but I can't seem to find any way of getting it. Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Scene Kit automatically updates the position of the node that owns an `SCNPhysicsBody` based on the physics simulation, so `SCNNode.position` is the right property to look for.

The catch is that there are actually two versions of that node in play. The one you typically access is called the "model" node. It reflects the target values for properties you set, even if you set those properties through an animation. The [`presentationNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/presentationNode) reflects the state of the node currently being rendered — if an animation is in progress, the node's properties have intermediate values, not the target values of the animation.

[Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNAction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNAction), physics, [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNConstraint), and any scene graph changes you make inside [update/render loop methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/SCNSceneRendererDelegate) directly target the "presentation" version of your scene graph. So, to read node properties that have been set by the physics simulation, get the [`presentationNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/presentationNode) for the node you're interested in (the node that owns the vehicle's `chassisBody` physics body), then read the presentation node's `position` (or other properties).

Comment: and to get the presentationNode: node.presentationNode

Comment: This was exactly what I was missing. Thanks! :)

Comment: How about changing a node's position? I have tried updating the `node.position` property and `node.presentationNode.position` property, but no luck... What am I missing?

Comment: The transform (including position) of a node with a dynamic physics body is managed by the physics simulation. It's best to find a way to do whatever you need to it through physics--e.g. applying an impulse. (This is what Apple's vehicle sample code does to right the car if it flips over.) If you have to set the position/rotation/etc directly, call `resetTransform` to get the physics back in sync with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my player node.
I move it with `applyForce` (to manage collision detection).
But when i check node position after some movement, the node position has not move (presentation node is the actual position as rickster write in his answer)
I manage to update the scnNode.position with renderer loop
You have to set position of your node with the `presentationNode` position.

```
node.position = node.presentationNode.position
```

Set this into `renderer(_: updateAtTime)` and your node position will sync with any animation you made to the physicsBody